# Improve Pandas read.excel speed

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to run through over 2250 excel files and perform some analysis on past results.

The problem is each file has about 60000+ rows but each file I only need 10-50 rows per file. The size is due to how they were splitting the excel file for assignment. (Duplicated file where they hid rows)

This is my script. I need to make sure the file has 88 columns, so it appends correctly.
I need the Agent filter but wondering if there is a more efficient way to run a similar script. It takes approx. 15- 25 sec to run each loop.

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
df = []
for i in range(len(AWV)):
    try:
        content = pd.read_excel(AWV[i], index_col= False)
        if content.shape[1] == 88:
            content = content[content['Agent'].isna() == False]
            df.append(content)
            print(str(AWV[i]) + ' Has been loaded')
        else:
            print('FAILED LOAD ' + AWV[i])
    except:
        print(' Was not able to be loaded' + AWV[i])
```

Any additional help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

I included the if statement to help do a quick check. I thought about only loading the first row to check shape and if it passes parameter then load the whole df. I figured that would improve speed a little bit but hoping to find a better way or a different package from Pandas.

Comment: Have you considered parallelizing this script with `ray` or a similar package?

Comment: the 10-50 rows are scattered across the entire table or are they always at the top? because if so you could use the nrows argument when reading the excel file. otherwise the na_filter might be helpful.

Comment: @nathan liang I will look into ray never heard of it.

Comment: @maxxel_ sadly no. Or I would use the nrow function. They should always be grouped together tho.

Comment: @Mrbowtie damn yea well i just know that excel files in general are a pain in the ass. i tried to read in an excel file with around 2-3 mio rows and it wouldn't even finish after like 10 minutes. when i converted the excel file into 3 .csv files it took around 5-10 seconds to read all of those lol

Comment: @maxxel_ Maybe that might be of interest. Makes me wonder how long it would take to convert everything into a .csv I have time lol. Only on May of 2022 after 2 and half hours of running.

Comment: @Mrbowtie the thing is that i saved these 3 .csv files by hand, i don't think you want to do that with your 2000+ files so yeaa